# Работа плеера в спящем режиме

Tags: ios, objective-c

Использую в приложении китайскую библиотеку `KrVideoPlayer`, при вводе в спящий режим проигрыватель отключается а при возврате продолжает играть.
Библиотека построена на базе `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Можно ли как-нибудь не прерывать работу переходом в спящий режим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках проекта, в разделе `Capabilities` выберите `Background Modes - Audio`, а так же для плеера укажите категорию `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`

Comment: Для проигрывания используется класс 'Media Player'